# Django/Python: Tried to update field with a model instance. Use a value compatible with CharField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a Django project in which type-1 users can create a Post and type-2 users can bid on a post. Finally, post_owner can accept a bid. In my Post model there is a CharField 'bidder' which sets to '0' as default. After accepting I wanted to  update this field with bidder_id as in accepted bid. I written an updated view for this field in my Auction view.

But it raising an error : Tried to update field MyApp1.Post.bidder with a model instance, . Use a value compatible with CharField. I would appreciate helping me solve this.

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    item = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    post_owner = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    bidder = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=0)

class Bid(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name = bids)
    amount = models.IntegerField(max_length = 20)
    bidder = models.ForeingKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Auction(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='auctions')
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    bid = models.OneToOneField('truck.Bid', related_name='auctions')
```

forms.py:

```
class AcceptedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    bidder = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('bidder', )
```

Views.py:

```
def live_bids(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        instance_post = Post.objects.get( id = request.POST['post_id'])
        form = AcceptedForm(request.POST,  instance = instance_post)

        post = Post.objects.get( id = request.POST['post_id'] )
        bid = Bid.objects.get(id = request.POST['bid_id'])
        if form.is_valid():
        accepted = form.save(commit=False)
        accepted.bidder = bid.bidder
        accepted.save()
        form.save()

    else:
        form = AcceptedForm()


    return render(request, 'live_bids.html', 'form':form)
```

live_bids.html:

```
<form class="nomargin" method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
{{form.bidder}}
<input type='hidden' name='post_id' value='{{post.id}}'/>
<input type='hidden' name='bid_id' value='{{bid.id}}'/>
<input type='submit' value='Accept'/>
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\sumanth\Desktop\django-custom-user-master\search field\Project\mysite\personal\views.py" in live_bids
  323.      if form.is_valid() :

File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  161.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  153.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  364.         self._post_clean()

File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in _post_clean
  380.             self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, exclude)

File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in construct_instance
  60.             f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])

File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in save_form_data
  865.         setattr(instance, self.name, data)

File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __set__
  207.                     self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /live_bids/
Exception Value: Cannot assign "''": "Post.bidder" must be a "EmailUser" instance.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in view. You cant do this:

```
 bid = Bid.objects.get(id = request.POST['bid_id'])
        if form.is_valid():
            accepted = form.save(commit=False)
            accepted.bidder = bid.bidder
```

because **accepted.bidder** is **CharField** and **bid.bidder** is **UserModel**
so you can do either:

```
bid = Bid.objects.get(id = request.POST['bid_id'])
    if form.is_valid():
        accepted = form.save(commit=False)
        accepted.bidder = str(bid.bidder_id) # add User.id as string
```

**OR I think better solution is make little changes**

```
class AcceptedForm(forms.Form):
    bidder = forms.InteferField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    post_id = forms.InteferField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    bid_id = forms.InteferField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        fields = ('bidder', 'post_id', 'bid_id')
```

and view:

```
if request.method=='POST':
    form = AcceptedForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = Post.objects.get( id = form.cleaned_data['post_id'] )
        bid = Bid.objects.get(id = form.cleaned_data['bid_id'])
        post.bidder = bid.bidder # You set post.bidder instance so you have to change model
        post.save()
else:
    form = AcceptedForm()
```

and models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   item = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   post_owner = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
   # Bidder should be User Foreign Key, but you have to set related_name, because you already have one User FK in model
   bidder = models.ForeingKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='posts_bidded')
```

and template:

```
<form class="nomargin" method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<input type='submit' value='Accept'/>
```

But I dont know purpose of bidder field, even in your code you override the field bidder anyway.

Comment: @when i did this, It raising an error Cannot assign "''": "Post.bidder" must be a "EmailUser" instance.

Comment: I edited it you can fix it if you change accepted.bidder = bid.bidder to accepted.bidder = str(bid.bidder_id), but I think you should consider the changes I proposed